# How to access a specific value from a Map <Object> flutter

Tags: flutter

Need to access a single value when the item is selected in the list.
When the item is clicked, it prints the whole list of objects, instead the value of the selected object.
For example, when user selects Spanish, should print SP instead of the list of objects.
I have a class and a list for the languages, but for this question is not relevant.

This is what I have achieved so far:

```
 List <Object> Dictionary = [
{'Spanish': 'SP'},
{'Italian': 'IT'},
{'German': 'DE'},
{'Arab': 'AR'},
{'Greek': 'GR'},
{'Thai': 'TH'},
{'Chinese': 'CH'},
{'French': 'FR'}
```

];

```
  List<Language> newDataList;
  final finalList = dictionary.values.toList();

  onItemChanged(String value) {
    setState(() {
      newDataList = languages.where((lang) => lang.title.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase())).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    newDataList = [...languages];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                hintText: 'Type languages',
              ),
              onChanged: onItemChanged,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              children: newDataList.map((data) {
                return Ink(
                  color: data.selected ? TheBaseColors.lightGreen : Colors.transparent,
                  child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(data.title),
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          data.selected = !data.selected;

                          print("${data.title} is now ${data.selected ? "selected" : "not selected"}");
                          print(Dictionary);

                        });
                      }),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Column(children: [
            Text('Selected languages :'),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                    children: newDataList.where((l) => l.selected).map((l) => Padding(child: Text(l.title), padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10))).toList()))
          ]))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tried dictionary.value, dictionary[value]

Comment: It prints the whole list because of this : `print(Dictionary);`

Comment: Yes, but how to access to value

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `List<Object>` you want to use `Map<String, String>` for this.

```dart
 Map<String, String> dictionary = {
  'Spanish': 'SP',
  'Italian': 'IT',
  'German': 'DE',
  'Arab': 'AR',
  'Greek': 'GR',
  'Thai': 'TH',
  'Chinese': 'CH',
  'French': 'FR'
};
```

If you use this you can easily do `dictionary['Spanish']` and receive 'SP' as value.

Comment: What I need to achieve is when the user selects the item, the value is printed. But I can't access to the value. Your response only works if the user selects Spanish

Comment: Then there’s probably something wrong with the state you set. Can you edit your post with your changed code? A map is still what you want to use over a list here.